# Передать int переменную из Activity в Fragment с помощью Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Имеется `Activity` и `Fragment`, нужно передать переменную типа `int Id` из `Activity` в `Fragment` для дальнейшего использования, я пробовал через `bundle` и все время вылетает ошибка `NullPointerException` и ссылается на то что в фрагменте в переменную `Id` ничего не приходит

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Код в `Fragment`:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
    private int id;
    public static MapFragment newInstance(String key,int value) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(key,value);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

    id = this.getArguments().getInt("id");

    return view;
    }
}
```

И код в `Activity`:

```
public class ChooseWarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_war);

    int id = 15;
                MapFragment fragmentID = MapFragment.newInstance("id",id);
    }
}
```

Подскажите как можно сделать по другому или в чем моя ошибка, а то уже голову сломал?

**UPD**

Может ли это быть связанно с типом добавления фрагмента?Вроде делал по шаблону и при нажатии кнопки появляется фрагмент,вдруг прояснит что-нибудь

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapFragment gameFragment;
    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);


        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        gameFragment = new MapFragment();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameInfo);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameStartbtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.container, gameFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей `GameActivity` вы создаёте фрагмент через конструктор `gameFragment = new MapFragment();`, а не через `newInstance()`. Соответственно никакие аргументы в него не попадают. Отсюда при обращении к аргументам внутри фрагмента у вас `NullPointerException`. Замените код создание фрагмента на тот, что в вашем первом примере:

```
...
gameFragment = MapFragment.newInstance("id", id);
...
```

Comment: Действительно,теперь я понял что к чему,спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, В Activity чтобы отправить `id`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", id);

MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

И получение во MapFragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null){
    id = getArguments().getInt("id");
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал так сделать и он перестал выдавать ошибку,ну и естественно это значит что bundle пришел пустым,так и как теперь поступить?

Comment: А как вы поняли что он пустой, так как я не вижу чтобы вы его (id) где то использовали?

Comment: В приложении попробовал использовать и просто пихнуть id в TextView,в итоге он проигнорировал данное действие и пошел дальше по коду,в целом выполнилось условия что Bundle==null и текст не подставился в TextView,да и в целом если убрать проверку if(bundle !=null) то снова ошибка

Comment: Попробовали обьявить Fragment и передать данные в методе `onClick()`?

Answer (score 1):

В `GameActivity` Вы создаете фрагмент непосредственно с помощью оператора `new`:

```
gameFragment = new MapFragment();
```

вместо того, чтобы использовать фабричный метод `newInstance(...)`. Соответственно, созданный фрагмент не имеет никаких аргументов, о чем свидетельствует исключение:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Большое спасибо,разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Вчитайтесь в текст ошибки:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Скорее всего, ошибка вылетает на строчке

```
id = this.getArguments().getInt("id");
```

Верно?

Ошибка говорит о том, что метод `getArguments()` возвращает `null`.

Если кратко — не зря же вам запрещают убирать дефолтный конструктор из фрагмента, и не всегда аргументы могут быть, а проверки у вас нет.

Сделайте вот так:

```
Bundle args = this.getArguments();

if (args != null) { /* делайте, что нужно */ }
```

Comment: Да,вы правы насчет места ошибки,вопрос как устранить

В целом дал ответ предыдущему оратору,т.к. примерно вы попросили одно и тоже проверить "Я попробовал так сделать и он перестал выдавать ошибку,ну и естественно это значит что bundle пришел пустым,так и как теперь поступить?"

Comment: @Кирилл не только вы вызываете ваш фрагмент — я написал в ответе, что не зря вас вынуждают оставлять дефолтный конструктор. Это означает, что не всегда аргументы будут иметься у вашего фрагмента. Просто не беспокойтесь, и на всякий случай выведите в лог тот случай, когда они не `null`. И проверьте уже в приложении: всё ли работает так, как надо?

Comment: наверно из-за нехватки знаний но ваш ответ я не совсем понял,просто прозвучало примерно как ну возможно аргумента и не будет у вашего фрагмента, но вы смиритесь,просто в любом случае остается проблема с тем что мне нужно получить значение с переменной ID и если это так не работает,то что делать?